# Reverse String recursively in C with return and a putBack function

Tags: c, recursion, return

So as homework, I need to implement the reverseRec function recursively. I can't use any loops, but must use the putBack function in it and the function needs to return something, which makes everything unnecessarily complicated. 
So after the recursion reaches the end of the string, it returns. If e.g. the string is "ABC", then it goes ABC-->BC-->C-->/0-->**C**-->**B**C-->**A**BC. My idea was, that I somehow save the beginning of the string (*s) of every returning recusion, and add them together with the putBack funcion to **CBA**. But I think this can't work, since it's a recursion, which means I can't save anything from any recursion depth, because it would be overritten, right?
 I feel like I'm missing something about how recursions and buffers work in C, but idk.

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"

int length(char *s) {
  int n = 0;
  while(*s != '\0') {
    n++;
    s++;
  }
  return n;
}

void copy(char* s, int n, char* t) {
  int i = 0;
  while(i < n) {
    t[i] = s[i];
    i++;
  }
}

char* putBack(char* s, char c) {
  const int n =  length(s);
  char* r = malloc(sizeof(char) * (n+2));
  copy(s, n, r);
  r[n] = c;
  r[n+1] = '\0';
  return r;
}

char* reverseRec(char *s){     

    if(*s){                   
        reverseRec(s+1);
        s = putBack(s, *(s-1));           //???
    }
    return s;
}


int main() {
printf("%s", reverseRec("ABC"));
}
```

Comment: Related, you may find it surprising how many hits `[c] reverse string recursive` returns in the search box of this very site.

Comment: You've made a common recursion beginner's error -- `reverseRec()` returns a value but when you called it recursively, you failed to deal with that return value.

Answer (score 0):

example input string "12345" must become "54321"
your prof gave you a hint about. The recursiveness breaks the input string into smaller parts and then builds then 1 by 1 together. This means the amount of "recursive steps" are five for the input string "12345"

Hint 1: the inputs for reverseRec( ) are 
input 1: "12345" 
input 2: "2345"  
input 3: "345" 
input 4: "45" 
input 5: "5" 
 
Hint 2: the outputs from each reverseRec( ) are 
output 1: "54321" 
output 2: "5432" 
output 3: "543" 
output 4: "54" 
output 5: "5" 
 
Hint 3: since reverseRec( ) calls itself, it returns itself a value. This value can be used. 
reverseRec 1( string ) gets "5434" 
reverseRec 2( string ) gets "543" ( the called reverseRec3 returns "543" ) 
reverseRec 3( string ) gets "54" ( the called reverseRec4 returns "54" ) 
reverseRec 4( string ) gets "5" ( the called reverseRec5 returns "5" ) 
reverseRec 5( string ) gets nothing ( no next reverseRec was called to get a value from) 
 
Hint 4: now you got a set of information and a missing objective 
given information (inputs) from Hint 1: 
given information (outputs) from Hint 2: 
returned value from Hint 3: 
 
reverseRec 1( string ) gets "5434", should return "54321", given input string "12345" 
reverseRec 2( string ) gets "543", should return "5432", given input string "2345" 
reverseRec 3( string ) gets "54", should return "543", given input string "345" 
reverseRec 4( string ) gets "5", should return "54", given input string "45" 
reverseRec 5( string ) gets nothing, returns 5, given input "5" 
 
Hint 5: the missing objective 
you must create the [should return "output"] for step 4,3,2,1 
you got the return value, the input string, and putBack 
 
The information is 80% of the work ;) now sit down and test some ideas with putback, 
or use the debugger to go step by step to see what is happening when. 
 
reverseRec( ) { 
// recursive magic

Answer (score 0):

From my perspective, you've *two* obstacles to overcome.  First is the recursion using `putBack()` and the second is that `putBack()` malloc's strings at each level of recursion that you need to free up to avoid a memory leak.  Here's my solution:

```
char* reverseRec(char* s) {

    if (length(s) > 1) {
        char* r = putBack(reverseRec(s + 1), *s);
        copy(r, length(r), s);
        free(r);
    }

    return s;
}
```

Since we are reversing a string, we know the copy will always fit back into the original.  The complete code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int length(char* s) {
    int n = 0;

    while (*s++ != '\0') {
        n++;
    }

    return n;
}

void copy(char* s, int n, char* t) {
    int i = 0;

    while (i < n) {
        t[i] = s[i];
        i++;
    }
}

char* putBack(char* s, char c) {
    const int n = length(s);
    char* r = calloc(n + 2, sizeof(char));

    copy(s, n, r);
    r[n] = c;
    r[n + 1] = '\0';

    return r;
}

char* reverseRec(char* s) {

    if (length(s) > 1) {
        char* r = putBack(reverseRec(s + 1), *s);
        copy(r, length(r), s);
        free(r);
    }

    return s;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    printf("%s\n", reverseRec(argv[1]));

    return 0;
}
```

This assumes `argv[]` strings are mutable -- if they aren't, copy it into a newly malloc'd string.

**OUTPUT**

```
% ./a.out abcdef
fedcba
%
```